# How to sort a column with custom renderer in Handsontable?

Tags: jquery, handsontable, custom-renderer

Handsontable version 0.34.2 (may not be able to upgrade)

I have an index page with Handsontable showing customer information. First column is id column. It is a html link. If user click on it will see detail of customer. Table initially is sorted on last modified time of each record.

```
$('#custInfo').handsontable({
  data: custData,
  colHeaders: ['Cust No', 'Cust Name', ..., 'Last Mod Time'],
  columnSorting: true,
  columns: [ 
    { renderer: safeHtmlRenderer }, 
    {}, 
    ...
    { type: 'date', 
      dateFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY by:mm:as' }]
  ...
}];

  function safeHtmlRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringfy(value);
    td.innerHtml = escaped;
    return td;
  };
```

The table is like this on screen :

> 261  Mary  30-10-2018 17:30:17
>
> 83 Paul  12-12-2018 09:13:48

If click on first column to sort ascending order, the sort is just alphabetically. That is '261' comes before '83'.

How can I sort on customer number (but not the underneath link)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like very few questions are answered in StackOverflow. So let me answer my own question.

It turns out it doesn't matter if a column has custom renderer or not. What matters is the **compare function** you provide.

Please be alert the following works for version 0.34.2 (latest version, version 7 does not work)

Re: [Easy Ways to Sort Different Types of Data in Your App](https://handsontable.com/blog/articles/2016/6/easy-ways-to-sort-different-types-of-data-in-your-app) (Thank you this blog saves me.)

Using version 0.34.2, all examples in the reference page works perfectly.

> a[0] = row index
>
> a[1] = value

If CustNo in first row is '<a href="http://localhost/Cust/Details/178">178</a>', a[1] is the link.

linkA1 is an array of string from splitting a[1].

linkA2 = 178</a

linkA2[0] = 178 (but this one is still a string)

CustNoA = parseInt(linkA2[0]) returns an integer for doing number comparison.

```
columns: [
{ data: 'CustNo',
  renderer: safeHtmlRenderer,
  sortFunction: function(sortOrder) {
    return function(a, b) {
      var linkA1 = a[1].split(">");
      var linkA2 = linkA1[1].split("<");  // linkA1[1] => '178</a'
      var CustNoA = parseInt(linkA2[0]);  // linkA2[0] => '178'

      var linkB1 = b[1].split(">");
      var linkB2 = linkB1[1].split("<");
      var CustNoB = parseInt(linkA2[0]);

      if (CustNoA < CustNoB) {
        return sortOrder ? -1 : 1;
      }

      if (CustNoA > CustNoB) {
        return sortOrder ? 1 : -1;
      }

      return 0;
    }
  }
```